# Get item index (rownum)

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have table with 10 000 elements.

```
 IQuerable<IEntity> query = dataRep.Get<IEntity>()
                                   .Query();
```

I need to get the index(rownum) of selected `obj` without getting all table items

```
 var obj = query.Where( x => x.Name == "testName")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

The simple sql work fine :

```
 select name, id, r from 
 (
     select name, id, rownum r from collections order by id
 ) where name = 'testName';
```

How do this in Linq to NHibernate ?

**Edit:**

I tried add to `IEntity` class property `RowNumber` and mapping this on `hbm` as

```
  <property name="RowNumber" formula="rownum" />
```

But after

```
  var index = query.Where( x => x.Name == "testName")
                   .Select( x => x.RowNumber)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Get always `1` value

Comment: I assume Oracle? `rownum` is based on the position of the row within its result set, so if it's called at the top level of a query which returns only one result, it can only ever equal `1`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. You are right. If block `where name='testName'` will be at same level with `rownum` - result always be `1`

Comment: I had to remove a tag so I could add the Oracle one - I picked .NET, but you may have a different opinion; But this is going to come down to wrangling NHbernate to produce particular SQL specific to Oracle, so really needs overlap between those two technologies to hopefully get some expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just filter the query directly?

```
IQuerable<IEntity> query = dataRep.Get<IEntity>()
                                  .Query()
                                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "testName");
```

Edit:

To get the item you can project into an anonymous type:

```
var query = (from data in dataRep.Get<IEntity>().Query()
             where Name == "testName"
             select new
             {
                 id = data.id,
                 rowNumber = data.rowNumber
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need to get the index of the item, not the item.

Comment: @Kronos - Edited to show how you can project into an anonymous type to get the id/row number as stated in your SQL.

Comment: `IEntity` object does not contain property `rowNumber`!
data.rowNumber - will be compilation error!

Comment: You will have to either:  Add the property into the class definition or omit the rowNumber field.

Comment: I done it. But what mapping should be for this property ? I tried use  `<property name="rowNumber" formula="rownum" />`. The value always `1`

Comment: @Kronos - I am unsure of your data source schema so it would be impossible to tell you. Try looking at what SQL returns based on the same query (You can use SQL Profiler to find this information out)

Comment: I hope you will not mind my edit. I made it's a bit more easy to read, also normalized syntax.

Comment: @abatishchev not at all - however the edit has broken the .Where clause of the query

Comment: In which of the paragraphs? Do you mean `FOD()` instead of `Where().FOD()`; or not-highlighted `where`?

Comment: @DarrenDavies I watched SQL, but still do not know how this property should be mapping.