# Get element page number

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have 10,000 items in a table that displays 20 items per page on client side( items can be additionally filtered)

I need to find item among all elements. Then I need to get the page number, where element located and go to that page on client and select it

My previous question is 
      [Get item index (rownum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226118/get-item-index-rownum) .

But I got no answer on it.

Probably there is another way to find the page number where item located without getting all table data?

I am using Linq to Nhibernate, Database - Oracle.

**Edit:** Thanks for replies, but it's not so easy

Example:

In table db, i have

```
 ID          NAME 
 1           Item1 
 2           
 3
 4
 5
 20
 31
 .....        ....
 5000
```

In client side, i filtered data

```
query = query.Where(...).Where(...).Where(...).OrderBy(...)
```

and got result

```
 ID                                         ROW_NUM_IN_QUERY
 4                                          1
 300                                        2
 2                                          3
 31                                         4
 .....        ....
 402                                        50
 800                                        51
```

I can't link to field `ID` or another in query, because they may be in a different order

I can get rownum at simple SQL. But Linq to NHibernate can't do it. It havn't function something like `IndexOf` or `RowNumber` without full getting data from table.

this variant :

```
var indexed = myDataSource.Select( (x,n) => new { Value = x, RowNumber = n } );

Not suported exception during execute query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I abandoned this idea, because i could not implement it with Nhibernate Linq.

But I use easier variant.

I use search as **quick filter** - display all found data in grid, without going to the page of first found element.

**Thx** for all replies and comments.

Answer (score 4):

First off, if you don't provide any ordering then the entire concept of an index is meaningless.  Next, there is no simple, easy way to get what you want; it will need to be somewhat dependent on the specific query.

If, say, you're ordering the data based on created by date you could do something like this:

```
var someItem = queryToFetchIndividualItem;

var indexOfItem = table.OrderBy(item => item.CreatedDate)
//any other filtering provided on your query goes here, i.e. other where statements
.Where(item => item.CreateDate < someItem.CreatedDate)
.Count()
```

if you're sorting on a "Title" then you could do something like this:

```
var indexOfItem = table.OrderBy(item => item.Title)
//any other filtering provided on your query goes here, i.e. other where statements
.Where(item => item.Title < someItem.Title)
.Count()
```

I assume you see the pattern here.  If we get the count of items that would come before the interesting item in the query we get the index.  The database can optimize the query for the fact that we're only interested in the count.

Comment: But how do you know at what index a particular item would be?  I think what the OP is asking is that if he selects an arbitrary item (probably through some filter), how does he know what page it will be on?

Comment: @villecoder That's exactly what this query does, or at least what it's intended to do.  I edited in a comment to make that more clear.  The idea is that you take whatever the relevant query is, tack on a "where the item comes before the 'current item'" and then grab the count.

Comment: @Kronos While the edit isn't bad, I already had that understanding to begin with.  Have you tried using this solution?  Is there some particular problem adapting this concept to your queries?

Comment: @Servy. No. But is a nice idea. It all depends on the order by. In my solution i can sort at any field or no sort

Comment: @Kronos As I said before, if there is no sorting then there is no meaningful index that you can use.  If you don't know what you're sorting on there is no general purpose method of finding an item's index without actually fetching every item that comes before it.

Comment: @Servy Got it. Clever :)  Count the items that are returned. Enjoy this here upvote!

Comment: @Servy. I can't fetch all :) There is one method with rownum fieled ( I write it at my first question ). But I can't do that with Nhibernate.

Comment: @villecoder it work only when you know sort field. When you don't know it or you havn't sorting, method not work =(

Comment: @Kronos true. If you have nothing to order by, you're screwed.  But how about ordering by the Primary key (if one's available). Otherwise, you may need to use a stored procedure.

Comment: @villecoder I can't use procedure. I have all in Linq =(. Many conditons apply to query and then displaied at my grid. I have idea create custom HqlBuilder. But exactly don't know, how it help me and how i can do that.

Comment: @Kronos I've already told you that if you apply those constraints it's not possible.  To do this in LINQ you either need to know what you're sorting on or you need to fetch every item up to the item of interest.  If you want to solve this you'll need to remove some of your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the indexed overload of select (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
var indexed = myDataSource.Select( (x,n) => new { Value = x, RowNumber = n } );
```

This gives you an enumeration of anonymous classes that contain the row number.  From there, you can get a specific record:

```
var specificRecord = indexed.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Value.Key == "SomeKey" );
```

Assuming that doesn't return `null` (i.e., your key was found), you can then get the page it's on with some simple math:

```
var page = (int)Math.Floor( (double)specificRecord.RowNumber / pageSize );
```

**Note**: you will have to test this method to see if it gets handled in the database, or has to pull your ten thousand records into memory; I've only tested it without a database, so it may not be very efficient.  If this does not work, then I recommend creating a stored procedure in your database that returns the row and page number.

Comment: OP will need to test, but I doubt this will be translated into a DB query.

Comment: Yeah. It can't translate to sql

Comment: Bummer.  I figured that would be the case, but sometimes I'm surprised what LINQ can translate into SQL.  Anyway, it sounds like your best bet is a stored procedure....